# Adding ActiveRecord validations to PaperTrail's Version model?

Tags: ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to add a validation to PaperTrail::Version which will prevent sensitive data from being stored in the versions table.  The idea being you'll get lots of obvious errors if you forget to sanitize your has_paper_trail call within your model.

If I add a custom validator in config/initializers/paper_trail it works ... for a while.  Then PaperTrail starts acting with its default behavior and my methods are undefined.

Example Code:

```
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load! 

module PaperTrail
  class Version

    # Ensure no sensitive values end up in the versions table
    validate  :prohibited_attributes

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a **custom version class**. See documentation [section 6.a. Custom Version Classes](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#6a-custom-version-classes).

> #### 6.a. Custom Version Classes
>
> You can specify custom version subclasses with the `:class_name`
> option:
>
> ```
> class PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version
>   # custom behaviour, e.g:
>   self.table_name = :post_versions
> end
>
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_paper_trail :class_name => 'PostVersion'
> end
> ```

Using `PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!`  was a good idea. Not sure why that didn't work for you. Hopefully this is a workaround.